# OnServerClick for button not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an html button and I'd like to have a server side click event but it's not firing when the button is clicked and the page does a postback. The button is inside the `ItemTemplate` for an `<asp:ListView id="usersListView"/>` that renders a table of information.

aspx

```
<button runat="server" id="delete" class="btn btn-mini" title="Delete" OnServerClick="delete_Onclick"></button>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void delete_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ListViewItem listViewItem = (ListViewItem)((Button)sender).NamingContainer;
    if(listViewItem != null) {
        Membership.DeleteUser(((Label) listViewItem.FindControl("userName")).Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `AutoEventWireup="true"` in the Page declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it will not work like this because events raised by nested controls placed in item templates should rather be handled by ListView's `ItemCommand` event.

For this to work then, you should set button's `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` and handle specific values in the listview's `ItemCommand`.

However, if I remember correcly, the `HtmlInputButton` does not have `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` properties. Instead, use `asp:Button`

```
 <asp:Button id="delete" runat="server" CommandName="something" CommandArgument="somethingelse" />
```

and handle the listview's itemcommand:

```
 protected void usersListView_ItemCommand( object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e )
 {
     switch ( e.CommandName ) { 
         case "something" : 
             // this is where you handle the button click
     }
 }
```

Note that `CommandArgument` is usually bound to an item-specific value (id perhaps) so that inside the server-side handler you can precisely identify the exact clicked button:

```
 <asp:Button id="delete" runat="server" CommandName="something" CommandArgument="<%# Eval( "id" ) %>" />

 protected void usersListView_ItemCommand( object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e )
 {
     switch ( e.CommandName ) { 
         case "something" : 
             // this is where you handle the button click
             var itemid = e.CommandArgument; 
     }
 }
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you Wiktor. I'm having an issue with the ItemCommand Event handler not firing though. I setup the ListView `OnItemCommand="usersListView_ItemCommand"` but nothing is happening, it's not hitting the handler at all when I click a delete button.