# Html control failing to hit codebehind method

Tags: asp.net

I have a html button control which is targeting to execute code behind method but it is failing to do so I googled but couldn't fix so far..

```
<td>
 <input type="button" runat="server" id="btnSend" class="btn" value="Send" onserverclick="btnSend_ServerClick" />
</td>
```

on view source I found the below..

```
   <input onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSend','')" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSend" type="button" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSend" class="btn" value="Send" />
```

and the code behind method is as belwo..

```
protected void btnSend_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}
```

don't know what's preventing from hitting the method any suggestion/help on this would be of gr8 help.

In addition to above would also like to mention that the control is with in
`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ComposeUpdatePanel" runat="server">` and tried following this link
[OnServerClick for button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487495/onserverclick-for-button-not-working)
without success..

Comment: I retagged your question. Please pay attention if you add a tag. [tag:website] had a *DO NOT USE* warning in its excerpt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue there was a textarea which has the content of the mail to which reply is being send and to display in format

> `<PRE>message content</PRE>`

so the  tag was causing the issue.

How ever removing the PRE tag causes the eventto fire but is there an alternate to retain format in TextArea so that the mail content would be displayed the way it was.